# Getting the duration of a uploaded file in javascriptI can't get this to work in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I can't get this to work in Firefox. I keep getting a "Uncaught TypeError: files is undefined" when I try to push files. Can you do the same for audio files?
Please help. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>

<p><div class="snippet" data-lang="js" data-hide="false" data- 
 console="false" data-babel="false">
 <div class="snippet-code">
 <pre class="snippet-code-js lang-js prettyprint-override"></pre>

 <script>

  var myVideos = [];

   window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    //document.getElementById('fileUp').onchange = setFileInfo;

   function setFileInfo() {
     //var files = this.fileUp.files;
     var files = this.files;
     myVideos.push(files[0]);
     var video = document.createElement('video');
     video.preload = 'metadata';

     video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
     window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
     var duration = video.duration;
     myVideos[myVideos.length - 1].duration = duration;
     updateInfos();

</script>

<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
<span>upload! (ღ˘⌣˘ღ)</span>
<input type="file" class="upload" id='fileUp' onchange = "setFileInfo()" 
name="fileUpload">
</div>
<pre id="infos"></pre>
```

Comment: how is `setFileInfo` called? you've commented that code. `document.getElementById('fileUp')` where is the element with id `fileUp`? You specifically state this doesn't work in firefox, does that mean it works in other browsers? how?

Comment: See the html at the bottom.

Comment: I see ... I don't think `this` will be what it would be if you used `addEventListener` ... you could do `onchange="setFileInfo(this)"` ... and `function setFileInfo(el) { var files = el.files; .....` - again, you'd need to do this for **all** browsers, not just firefox

Comment: of course, once you pass this hurdle, you'll have other issues - though, I suspect you haven't shown ALL your javascript, as the script you've shown is definitely incomplete - at least two unfinished functions in what you've posted

Comment: I got it to do what I wanted thanks